# JSON não converte carácter especial?

Tags: java, json, arraylist

Tenho uma `ArrayList` e quando vou converter ele para um `Json` usando o `Gson` os caracteres especiais não acompanham a serialização.

**Obs** Meu banco e projeto está no encoding `utf8`.

Estou serializando o `ArrayList` assim:

```
Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
ClienteDAO dao = new ClienteDAO();        
lista = dao.listaClientes(cliente,empresa,dataHoraExp,compartilhaBas);

Gson g = new Gson();
String json = g.toJson(lista);
```

Na minha varia `json` onde deveria apresentar `"bairro1":"NOSSA SRº DE FATIMA"`  está apresentando `"bairro1":"NOSSA SR? DE FATIMA "`.

Como faço para converter sem que eu perca os caracteres especiais?

Comment: Qual ide vc utiliza? vc está utilizando maven?

Comment: Estou usando o Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente sua ide está apontando outro enconding.

Se seu projeto estiver utilizando maven, basta apenas adicionar no .pom a seguinte propriedade:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

Se estiver utilizando gradle vai precisar adicionar:

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Agora se não estiver utilizando nenhum gerenciador de dependencias vc vai precisar setar as configurações em sua ide.
Se estiver utilizando o eclipse vc vai precisar ir em:

`Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding` e mudar o encoding para `utf-8`.

Se você utilizar o netbeans vc vai precisar ir no arquivo `netbeans.conf` e setar `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Outra opcao é em sua classe `main` na primeira linha de execução setar: `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");`

Comment: Era isso mesmo, fiz o que me orientou é deu certinho. Obrigada!!!